# Custom Partitioner Error

Tags: hadoop, partitioner

I am writing my own custom Partitioner(Old Api) below is the code where I am extending Partitioner class:

```
public static class WordPairPartitioner extends Partitioner<WordPair,IntWritable> {

   @Override
   public int getPartition(WordPair wordPair, IntWritable intWritable, int numPartitions) {
        return wordPair.getWord().hashCode() % numPartitions;
    }
}
```

Setting the JobConf:

```
conf.setPartitionerClass(WordPairPartitioner.class);
```

WordPair Class contains:
    private Text word;
    private Text neighbor;

Questions:
1. I am getting error:"actual argument class (WordPairPartitioner) cannot convert to Class (?extends Partitioner).
2. Is this a right way to write the custom partitioner or do I need to override some other functionality as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you are mixing up old API(classes from `org.apache.hadoop.mapred.*`) and new API(classes from `org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.*`)

Using old API, you may do as follows:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Partitioner;
public static class WordPairPartitioner implements Partitioner<WordPair,IntWritable> {

   @Override
   public int getPartition(WordPair wordPair, IntWritable intWritable, int numPartitions) {
        return wordPair.getWord().hashCode() % numPartitions;
    }


   @Override
   public void configure(JobConf arg0) {

   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks man! I don't know how come I forgot to modify the headers..thanks for concrete answer...I mixed old and new api''s ..:)

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Amar's answer, you should handle the eventuality of hashCode returning a negative number by bit masking:

```
@Override
public int getPartition(WordPair wordPair, IntWritable intWritable, int numPartitions) {
    return (wordPair.getWord().hashCode() % numPartitions) & 0x7FFFFFFF;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Chris...sure I'll take care of this.